Find or expand Sharepoint Page titleArea image - Microsoft Graph API
I have been struggling in the past days trying to find an related article/documentation about the Sharepoint Graph API site page image which is inside the titleArea or thumbnailWebUrl.
There is no proper documentation how to achieve this, there are many subfolders being created where the images get stored into the "Site Assets" or more preferably inside Site Contents - there are many subfolders and it's never accurate to properly automate this for each page that are stored inside a site, has anyone achieved this matter to retrieve an public CDN url for the images?
I am using OAuth granted generated tokens with offline access and scopes: Sites.ReadWrite.All Files.Read.All
I have tried many ways like:

automate into the "drives" and search for the image name (unsuccessful)
tried many articles, never a proper one always different thing


Could you share imageWebUrl inside titleArea?

"thumbnailWebUrl": "/sites/mypersonalsite/SiteAssets/SitePages/1g33v8at/77787-Copy-of-Header-Vorlage--6-.png",
Sometimes very different but this is the 1st example.

that is the "imageWebUrl" but I have renamed it to "thumbnailWebUrl" sorry if any confusion is caused.

I would retrieve all SharePoint lists including the hidden one to find out the id of Site Assets list
GET /v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists?$select=id,displayName,description,system

One of the returned list should have the displayName like Site Assets (or localized name). Use the list id in the next request to find out the drive related to Site Assets list
GET /v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{site_assets_list_id}/drive

Now, use driveId and rest of the URL after SiteAssets in thumbnailWebUrl
/sites/mypersonalsite/SiteAssets/SitePages/1g33v8at/77787-Copy-of-Header-Vorlage--6-.png
=>
SitePages/1g33v8at/77787-Copy-of-Header-Vorlage--6-.png as a relative path to get driveItem related to the image in the title area.
GET /v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{relative_path}:/
GET /v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/SitePages/1g33v8at/77787-Copy-of-Header-Vorlage--6-.png:/

